# Update database rows

Tags: php, mysql

Let us say we've database table `my_table` with the following structure

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
`title` text,
`name` text
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `admin` VALUES ('my title', 'my name');
```

Now i want to update it to be with 1 extra field `slogan` to be like this

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
`title` text,
`name` text,
`slogan` text
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `admin` VALUES ('my title', 'my name', 'my slogan');
```

For sure if it 10 or even 100 i can do it using regex with any text editor but i it too huge for my processor to do it so i've been thinking to use PHP to update my table while it on my hosting server.

I've been thinking to use

```
$q1 = "CREATE TABLE `my_table`(
`slogan` text )";
mysql_query($q1) or die(mysql_error()." at row ".__LINE__);
```

but given me error `my_table` already exist
so any help ~ thanks

Comment: To be honest, I don't quite get the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` ADD COLUMN `slogan` text;
```

followed by lots of

```
UPDATE `my_table` SET `slogan`='...' WHERE `title`=' ... ';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try that:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD slogan text;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `CREATE TABLE` that is for creating new table but as you saying you already created table and just want to add new column slogan. So you need to use [**ALTER Table**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) syntax.

So use alter query as described in other posts:

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` ADD COLUMN `slogan` text
```